# How to skip reading first line from file when using fileinput method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing this to read the file:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('/home/manish/java.txt'):
  if not fileinput.isfirstline():
...             data = proces_line(line);
...             output(data)
```

It is throwing error as proces_line is not defined.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'proces_line' is not defined
```

I have to read the data line by line and store in list, each line being separate element of list.

Comment: Where have you defined `proces_line`?

Comment: I have looked into this and tried, assuming proces_line is method but I guess i am wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523378/elegant-way-to-skip-first-line-when-using-python-fileinput-module

Comment: `proces_line` is not a built-in function in Python , you should write it yourself

Comment: Why do you need `fileinput` at all? Do you want to modify the file you're reading?

Comment: I have to just read the line from file and store as list ignoring first line

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes I need to modify this file and do write operation on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the first line as follows:

```
import fileinput

def output(line):
    print(line)


fi = fileinput.input('/home/manish/java.txt')
next(fi)    # skip first line

for line in fi:
    output(line)
```

This avoids you having to test for a first line each time in the for loop.

---

To store each of the lines into a list, you could do the following:

```
import fileinput

fi = fileinput.input('/home/manish/java.txt')
next(fi)    # skip first line
output = list(fi)
fi.close()

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
fname = '/home/manish/java.txt'
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

`content` is of type `list`. You can ignore `content[0]` and loop through with the rest to fetch the required data.

Comment: Sorry, I am bound to use fileinput method

Comment: Why? This only makes sense if you want to iterate over multiple files in sequence, or if you want to change the lines as you're reading them. From your question, it doesn't look like you're trying to do that - Sameer wrote exactly how to do what you stated in your question.

Comment: Of course, you could do `content = f.readlines()[1:]` and chop off the first line right away.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the "readline ()" fuction. Pulls in the next line from the file and truncated the newline [Python documentation for File Input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)

Usage

```
For each in openFile:
    List += openFile.readline ()
```

In addition, you are trying to use a function that does not exist. As well as being miss spelled.